# How to change store state after API update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let's say I have a POST request that updates the status of a property in an object to true / false.

In my reducer, I have this dispatched as an action after that post request is successful.

```
case "ADD_CHANGE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE":
    if (action.res.errorCode == 0) {
        console.log("NO ERROR!");
        // DO SOMETHING
   }
```

Currently, the status can be changed in the backend but unless I refresh the page, then the 'true' status isn't reflected in the DOM (am doing a GET request on componentDidMount() to get the latest data when the page refreshes).

My question is how do I change the state in the store immediately after the post request (POST request is triggered by a click of a button)?

Do I do this?

```
case "ADD_CHANGE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE":
    if (action.res.errorCode == 0) {
        console.log("NO ERROR!");
        const objChanged = newState.list.find(function (obj) { return obj.id === action.res.data.id; });
        objChanged.is_favorite = true;
```

Considering that I have this as my state in the store:

```
const currentState = [
    {
        list: []
    }
];
```

I'm very new to redux / react, so am not sure if I'm doing it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate the state value directly. Also while dispatching the actions after a successful API request, you can just pass the id as the payload for the request

```
dispatch({
   type: 'ADD_CHANGE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE',
   id: res.data.id
})
```

Now in the store, you can process like

```
case "ADD_CHANGE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE": {

    const objIndex = state.list.findIndex(function (obj) { return obj.id === action.id; });
    if(objIndex > -1) {
         // return the updated state if the id was found
         return {
              ...state,
              list: [
                  ...state.list.slice(0, index), 
                  {...state.list[objIndex], is_favorite: true},
                  ...state.list.slice(index + 1)
              ]
         }
    }
    // otherwise return the state as it is
    return state
}
```

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention that the newState is already a copy as in I've declared on top of my reducer something like -> let newState = Object.assign({}, currentState);. If it's already the copy, then is my example correct?

Comment: When you use Object.assign, your state is just copied, one level deep and hence the inner objects within the List will still point to the same reference

Answer (score 0):

you can store state as

```
this.setState({[stateName]:value});
```

in case you are using ajax or axios, you have to bind the function first like

this.apicallfunction = this.apicallfunction.bind(this);

Answer (score 0):

By passing the id in action, you can update it using 'react-addons-update':

```
import update from 'react-addons-update'

case "ADD_CHANGE_TO_TRUE_RESOLVE": {
         if(action.id > -1){
              return update(state, {
                    list: {
                        [action.id]: {
                            is_favorite: { $set: true }
                        }
                    }
                })
          }
          else{
               return state
          }
}
```